# C# WinRT - Create and modify buttons from code behind

Tags: c#, button, windows-8, windows-runtime, code-behind

I looking for some solutions, but find nothing about it. I would like to simply create buttons from code behind and modify them how i wants. The idea is to create a button which can use "Tapped" or "Clicked" method.

But when i want to add the method "Tapped" I can't find how. Have you any ideas ?

```
button = new Image { Width = 100 , Height = 100 };
button.Source = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Assets/image.png"));
Canvas.SetLeft(button, width);
Canvas.SetTop(button, height);
canvasPlan.Children.Add(button);
```

I found this thing, but i don't know how to use it :

```
button.Tapped += .. ?
```

Thanks for your time,
Regards.

Comment: `I would like to simply create buttons from code behind and modify them how i wants.` - Don't create UI elements in code. That's what XAML is for.

Comment: @HighCore That's nice and all when you have a static UI.  Sometimes for a dynamic UI it's easier to do it in code.  Also, some people just like to know how things work under the hood.

Comment: @mydogisbox If your UI is dynamic you should use `DataTemplates`, and `ItemsControl`s and other XAML-based techniques. This is not (crappy and hack-prone) winforms. get used to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`button.Tapped +=` is an event. You'll need to assign an event-handler using the  `+=` syntax.
The event-handler is a method that has the signature `public void EventHandler(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)`.

You'll need to define what is to happen in the body of the method:

```
public void EventHandler(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e){
 //determine what happens here
}
```

See the [Button-Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.button) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br230232.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I learn something really great thanks to you :)

Comment: @Sw1a you are very welcome. First steps are the toughest! But please consider what mydogisbox said, too. He is right, too.